# SVG foreignObject textarea and text elements have their characters inverted on the x-axis

Tags: html, svg, textarea, autodesk-forge, foreignobject

I'm creating a custom measuring tool for the Autodesk Forge Viewer (Markupscore extension).
I have achieved the line-drawing part with the SVG `<path>` tag fairly easily. However, I want to render a `<textarea>` for the user to enter a numerical value once the `onMouseUp` event is called (once the user has finished drawing the line). To do this I'm using a `foreignObject`, with a textarea for input and a text tag to display the text.
For some reason, the characters I enter into this textarea are "upside down". The textarea itself is not; the writing direction is still left → right. It is just the individual characters that are upside down. It looks like this:

[image]

and the generated markup looks this:

```html
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" layer-order-id="markups-svg" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; transform:scale(1,-1); -ms-transform:scale(1,-1); -webkit-transform:scale(1,-1); -moz-transform:scale(1,-1); -o-transform:scale(1,-1); transformOrigin:0, 0; -ms-transformOrigin:0, 0; -webkit-transformOrigin:0, 0; -moz-transformOrigin:0, 0; -o-transformOrigin:0, 0; " width="1550" height="600" viewBox="-101.7644738631413 25.603030631786396 488.57934430714505 189.12748319689365" pointer-events="painted" cursor="crosshair">
   <g cursor="default">
      <g cursor="inherit" pointer-events="stroke">
         <path id="markup" d="m 0 5 v 0 -10 m -5 0 l 10 10 M 0 0 L 79.59484653519095 0 m 0 5 v 0 -10 m -5 0 l 10 10" stroke-width="0.49516667683974447" stroke="rgba(255,0,0,1)" fill="none" transform="translate( 25.07833084584351 , 104.7208155667812 ) rotate( 0 )"></path>
         <path id="hitarea" fill="transparent" stroke="transparent" d="m 0 5 v 0 -10 m -5 0 l 10 10 M 0 0 L 79.59484653519095 0 m 0 5 v 0 -10 m -5 0 l 10 10" stroke-width="9.95154083668433" transform="translate( 25.07833084584351 , 104.7208155667812 ) rotate( 0 )"></path>
         <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" transform="translate( 25.07833084584351 , 104.7208155667812 ) rotate( 0 )">
            <textarea rows="1" dir="auto" maxlength="10" data-i18n="Text" style="resize: none; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1; padding: 5px; line-height: 130%; left: 468px; top: 198px; width: 150px; color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-family: Arial; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; height: 23px; opacity: 0; border: 1px solid red;"></textarea>
            <text style="color: red; opacity: 1;">1234</text>
         </foreignObject>
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Any idea what's going on? I have tried resetting browser styles, I have tried fiddling with the `rotate` attribute, and I have tried adding namespace attributes to the SVG, none of which has any effect on the text orientation.
I'm completely new to working with SVG and `foreignObjects`, I'm sorry if I'm not being clear and not providing enough information.

Comment: you have transform:scale(1,-1) as a style on the svg element so you've deliberately set everything upside down.

Comment: Thank you Robert, this solved my problem. Have a great day.